# On vous a refait

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

A:  Ce tableau faisait deux mille au marché. Je l'ai payé mille.
B: On vous a refait!

Doe B mean “You did it!” “You accomplished a success’” or “You were tricked.” “You were set up”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends, but officaly, that means you were tricked:

http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/13605

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%AAtre_refait/67427

However, some young people use this expression in a positive way:

> "J'ai reussi mes examens, je suis refait !"

Which could be the equivalent of:

> "I passed, I did it !"
>
> "I passed, I suceeded !"

This expression is often used in a positive way by young people.

So as I see your sentence, I would say that he made a good deal.

Comment: I tend to disagree on the conclusion: *être refait* may mean "to be enthusiastic about something" but *refaire* (the active verb) means "to trick". So I understand *on vous a refait* only as "you have been tricked".

Comment: That's why I think this could be interesting to know the context behind this sentence, as "être refait" is more used by the young generation as positive, rather than previous generation who use it as negative.